How can I register a named HttpClient with asynchronous configuration using IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core?
I want to register and configure a named HttpClient with configuration that (may in general) require asynchronous code (async/await):
services.AddHttpClient(HttpClientConstants.UserManagementService, async (sp, client) =>
{
    var configuration = sp.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

    var baseAddress = configuration?.GetValue<string>("UserManagementService:BaseUrl") ??
                      throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("UserManagementService:BaseUrl is missing");
    var scope = configuration?.GetValue<string>("UserManagementService:Scope") ?? throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("UserManagementService:Scope is missing");

    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true });
    var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { $"{scope}" }), CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"{baseAddress}/api/v1/users", UriKind.Absolute);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Token);
});

While the above code compiles, it fails at runtime. The signature of the used overload of AddHttpClient expects an Action, and believe I'm supplying a compatible Lambda function. If I rewrite the Lambda function to be synchronous (without async), it works.

Are Actions required for be synchronous?
Could I make the code work by using Func, which some answers to similar questions tell.
How can I call asynchronous code from a synchronous function?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-8.0

In sendasync implementation of handler before calling base.sendasync

@Selvin - Sorry, I don't understand what you mean, could you elaborate?

... DelegatingHandler.SendAsync ...  No elaboration since it is in multiple answers to similar questions here on SO

But it also needs to be compatible with AddHttpClient. Are you sure it is that?

Use a delegating handler. These can be registered with HttpClientFactory, but the authentication will happen at the point of requests being sent, not before they are returned by IHttpClientFactory.Create(). It is not possible to do asynchronous work as part of resolving the dependency through DI.

@MartinCostello Thank you. I will look into it. What's the reason that DI doesn't accept asynchronous work? Like it creates an instance using a synchronous factory, it could create an instance using an asynchronous factory and calling await on the Task<T>?

It could, but it doesn't. You can't do asynchronous work in the DI system because it isn't something it supports.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56204930/2557855
